# How to target class and set its background color differently to each class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<ul>
  <li>XXX</li>
  <li>XXX</li>
  <li class="period">12</li>
  <li class="period">13</li>
  <li class="period">14</li>
  <li class="period">15</li>
  <li class="period">18</li>
  <li class="period">19</li>
  <li class="period">20</li>
  <li class="period">21</li>
 </ul>
```

How can I target **period** class and set background color to each period class differently?

Couldn't my head around how to nail this.

I was thinking to use **nth-of-type** but no luck so far.

I also tried. **nth-child**. For example:

```
ul li.period:nth-child(1){
  background: green;
}
ul li.period:nth-child(2){
  background: blue;
}
ul li.period:nth-child(3){
 background: red;
}
```

But no luck!

Any clue would be appreciated.

I do have jquery solution:

```
$('.period').each(function (i) {
    $(this).addClass('period-' + i);
});
```

And then I can target period-0, period-1, But I need css way.

or another jquery

```
$( ".period:eq( 0 )" ).css( "opacity", "1" );
$( ".period:eq( 1 )" ).css( "opacity", "0.8" );
$( ".period:eq( 2 )" ).css( "opacity", "0.6" );
$( ".period:eq( 3 )" ).css( "opacity", "0.4" );
$( ".period:eq( 4 )" ).css( "opacity", "0.2" );
$( ".period:eq( 5 )" ).css( "opacity", "0.1" );
```

But I want pure css.

Comment: Pseudo-classes like `nth-child` match elements, not classes, and when you throw classes into the mix they end up acting like filters and usually don't do what you want. Will the number of elements without the period class change, or will there always be just two?

Comment: nth-child starts from the first child, so the `li` without class also counts. I am sure you can figure out the rest. You could also just add an extra class to each period

Comment: What is your goal of this? Is assigning an additional class or id unique to each one not a feasible option?

Comment: @Jake period class will be remain same. Can't add ID.

Comment: @Huangism, Think this is an runtime situation where I have no control. I want pure css solution.

Comment: @j08691, number of class will be always 6 and other list can grow or shrink.

Comment: I do have jquery solution but I want pure css.

Comment: read the duplicate question and you will understand there is no CSS solution